# Is that possible to use python pandas to construct portfolios by a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

Now I have a pandas dataframe that is similar to the table

| index | Date | return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-1 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 2017-2 | 0.2 |
| 1 | 2017-3 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 2017-1 | 0.4 |
| 2 | 2017-2 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 2017-3 | 0.6 |
| 3 | 2017-1 | 0.7 |
| 3 | 2017-2 | 0.8 |
| 3 | 2017-3 | 0.9 |
| 4 | 2017-1 | 1.0 |
| 4 | 2017-2 | 1.1 |
| 4 | 2017-3 | 1.2 |

And now the table contains 4 indexs in such order. I want constuct portfolio on **every 2 index**, keeping the date unchanged but portfolio return is the average of 2 index. So that the result will be 2 portfolios.

The target result is

| portfolio_index | Date | portfolio return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| portfolio 1 | 2017-1 | 0.25 |
| portfolio 1 | 2017-2 | 0.35 |
| portfolio 1 | 2017-3 | 0.45 |
| portfolio 2 | 2017-1 | 0.85 |
| portfolio 2 | 2017-2 | 0.95 |
| portfolio 2 | 2017-3 | 1.05 |

For example, the portfolio 1 should contains index 1 and 2, and have return on separate months.
Is there any possible solution?

```
import pandas as pd
db = pd.read_csv('17base.csv')
db = db.groupby(db['index'])['return'].mean()
```

Comment: please do not repost exacly yhe same question, provide a minimal complete input and the full matching expected output (with the real expected data, not empty cells)

Comment: If you want an explicit answer you need to provide enough details, SO is not here to help you meet your deadline but to provide the community with a pool of clearly understandable and reproducible questions that will be helpful to the most. Minimal, detailed, and reproducible questions usually get answered within minutes.

Comment: how can you divide the number of rows by two and still have 3 rows for index 1, 3 for index2 etc. the question is unclear. You **need** to provide a clear explicit example.

Comment: No, the 3 rows here are the date, you can see the portfolio 1 repeatedly appears 3 times, with three dates.

Comment: can you please provide a minimal but complete example (let's say 12 rows) that get collapsed into 6 rows (provide both input and output). I'm afraid that without a reproducible example your question will be unanswered/closed.

Comment: I believe it's complete right now. Thank you for you generous suggestions.

Comment: are you sure of the calculations? I expected 0.15 as the first value (0.1+0.2)/2, and 1.15 as the last one (1.1+1.2)/2

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the 0.25 is (0.1+0.4)/2, which is the average of two index in the same day, and 1.05 is (0.9+1.2)/2

Comment: Got it, but I have to say this was poorly described. Next time please make the effort to be explicit both in the data and the logic, so much wasted time otherwise…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need to craft a custom dataframe, with help of [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
N = 2 # number of values to group
M = 3 # number of Dates per portfolio
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'portfolio_index': df['index'].iloc[:len(df)//2],
                    'Date': df['Date'].iloc[:len(df)//2],
                    'portfolio return': df['return'].to_numpy().reshape(N,-1,M).mean(1).ravel()
                   })
```

output:

```
   portfolio_index    Date  portfolio return
0                1  2017-1              0.25
1                1  2017-2              0.35
2                1  2017-3              0.45
3                2  2017-1              0.85
4                2  2017-2              0.95
5                2  2017-3              1.05
```

Alternatively, with `pandas`:

```
N = 2
M = 3
group = 'portfolio_'+pd.Series(np.arange(len(df)//M)//N+1).astype(str)
(df
 .pivot(index='index', columns='Date', values='return')
 .groupby(group.values).mean()
 .rename_axis('portfolio_index')
 .stack()
 .reset_index(name='portfolio return')
)
```

output:

```
     portfolio    Date  portfolio return
0  portfolio_1  2017-1              0.25
1  portfolio_1  2017-2              0.35
2  portfolio_1  2017-3              0.45
3  portfolio_2  2017-1              0.85
4  portfolio_2  2017-2              0.95
5  portfolio_2  2017-3              1.05
```

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a custom group index that reflects which rows you want to aggregate together:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 12
df = pd.DataFrame({'return': np.linspace(0.1, 1.2, num=n)})

df['group'] = (np.tile([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], n // 6) 
              + np.repeat(np.arange(n // 2, step=3), 6))

df
```

```
    return  group
0   0.1     0
1   0.2     1
2   0.3     2
3   0.4     0
4   0.5     1
5   0.6     2
6   0.7     3
7   0.8     4
8   0.9     5
9   1.0     3
10  1.1     4
11  1.2     5
```

So that now you can group accordingly:

```py
df.groupby('group').mean()
```

```
    return
group   
0   0.25
1   0.35
2   0.45
3   0.85
4   0.95
5   1.05
```

Answer (score -1):

answer above has hard code more or less, here is mine

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.groupby('Date',as_index=False)['return'].mean()

df11=df1.assign(col1=df1[['index']].add(1).floordiv(2).astype(str)).groupby('col1').apply(function1).droplevel(1).reset_index().assign(portfolio_index="portfolio ")

df11.assign(portfolio_index=df11.portfolio_index.str.cat(df11.col1)).drop('col1',axis=1)
```

out

```
     Date  return portfolio_index
0  2017-1    0.25     portfolio 1
1  2017-2    0.35     portfolio 1
2  2017-3    0.45     portfolio 1
3  2017-1    0.85     portfolio 2
4  2017-2    0.95     portfolio 2
5  2017-3    1.05     portfolio 2
```